# MSI GX660 laptop power fluctuations

Tags: laptop, power-supply, battery, power

Okay. So my trusty laptop has come down with an issue. It won't always take my power supply, resulting in 2 cases.
One is that it simply does not receive the power, the other is more peculiar. 
The battery indicator will turn on/off about once a second in a steady pace, but there is not enough juice to keep the machine going.

Another thing to note is that the head of the charger can get very hot when inserted into the laptop. Doesnt always happen though.

My first thought was the charger of course. No dice, other power supply has same issue.

The power socket in the laptop does also not seem very loose if at all.

I have tried removing the battery. No change in behavior.

Moving the cable around inside the socket DOES have some effect, varying between power/indicator blinking on and off/ no power. So the problem must be around there.

My question then is, can anyone give a solid guess on what the problem is? If yes, can i solve it myself if i take the laptop apart?

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the charging circuit which means replacement of the PCB in question if it's even replaceable

Comment: What måles you think its not just the power jack?

Comment: Because you indicated it isn't the battery and "moving the cable around in the socket" helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now disassembled the laptop to fix the problem. The motherboard was entirely OK, the problem was the pin from the jack that goes into the motherboard (The one that leads the power). The solder on the motherboard was brown, bad and seemed off, although not loose. The solder was removed, the pin was resoldered and the computer now charges fine again.

In short; The DC jack had a bad connection to the motherboard. Solution was to resolder it.